# Speeding Ticket Application

Tags: java

I'm looking to get some advice on whether or not I am building/structuring my application the correct way. The program has a few key components:

- Calculate the fine based on how fast over the limit a driver was travelling
- Generate a fine letter address to the driver
- Update a file with a driver's registration details and the fine

So that being said, I have the following classes:

- `DriverDetails`
- `DriverManager`
- `Fine`
- `FineCalculator`
- `FineType`

Here is the idea:

When I want to work out the fine:

1. `FineCalculator` object is created
2. The speed limit is set
3. The speed of the car is set and then the `calculateFine()` method is called
4. The `calculateFine()` method will return a `Fine` object, which is a data object which contains an amount, and a string (the result), the points if any, a `FineType`

This is one side of the application.

The other part is to be done after a fine has been generated. The user will enter the driver details, a `DriverDetails` object will be created, for the user to then generate any form of documentation it will use the `DriverManager` object which will take a `DriverDetails` object when constructed.

The `FineCalculator` class:

```
public class FineCalculator {

    private int speedlimit;

    private int carspeed;


    public FineCalculator(int speedlimit, int carspeed) {

        this.speedlimit = speedlimit;
        this.carspeed = carspeed;
    }


    public Fine calculateFine() {

        Fine fine = new Fine();

        int milesover = carspeed - speedlimit;

        if(milesover < 1) { 

            fine.result = "The user was not going above the speed limit, no actions will be taken.";
        }

        else if(milesover < 5) {

            fine.result = "No fine issued, no points gained but a warning will be issued to the driver.";
            fine.finetype = FineType.WARNING;
        }

        else if(milesover > 4 && milesover < 10) {

            fine.result = "A fine of £50.00 will be issued to the driver. 0 points gained.";
            fine.amount = 50.00;
            fine.finetype = FineType.FIFTY;


        }

        else if(milesover > 9 && milesover < 15) {

            fine.result = "A fine of £100.00 will be issued to the driver. 0 points gained.";
            fine.amount = 100.00;
            fine.finetype = FineType.ONE_HUNDRED;

        }

        else if(milesover > 14 && milesover < 20) {

            fine.result = "A fine of £150.00 will be issued to the driver. 3 points gained.";
            fine.amount = 150.00;
            fine.points = 3;
            fine.finetype = FineType.THREE_POINTS_ONE_FITY;
        }

        else if(milesover > 19) {

            fine.result = "A fine of 1000.00 will be issued to the driver, and they will be disqualified.";
            fine.finetype = FineType.DISQUALIFIED;
        }

        return fine;

    }
}
```

The `Fine` class:

```
public class Fine {

    public Double amount;
    public String result;
    public int points;
    public FineType finetype;

}
```

The `DriverDetails` class:

```
public class DriverDetails {

    public String firstname, surname, address, city, postcode;
    public int drivernumber;

}
```

The `DriverManager` class:

```
public class DriverManager {

    private DriverDetails driverdetails;
    private Fine fine;

    public DriverManager(DriverDetails driverdetails, Fine fine) {

        this.driverdetails = driverdetails;
        this.fine = fine;
    }

    public void generateFineLetter() {


    }

    public void updateDriverDetailsWithFine() {


    }
}
```

And finally, the simple enum class:

```
public enum FineType  {

    WARNING, FIFTY, ONE_HUNDRED, THREE_POINTS_ONE_FITY, DISQUALIFIED

}
```

My biggest concern is the fact that I'm not using the getters/setters inside the `DriverDetails` and `Fine` data classes. I mean, it doesn't feel like the getters and setters are completely necessary. Am I wrong? I know what I'm doing goes completely against encapsulation, but in this scenario is that bad? Can I have any advice here as to what to improve or if I'm structuring this wrong?

Comment: I have rolled back your last edit. Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Instead of destroying your question, you could upvote + accept the best answer and upvote the ones that helpled you.

Answer (score 1):

It is a question of how much will the project expand beyond what is described here.  For instance, are you going to persist driver details and other data? if you are going to use a database, then you will probably want to use an Object-Relation-Mapping (ORM) framework, and they tend to expect Java Beans to work with. perhaps you will want to develop a web api that will send or receive such data in json format? json parsers/generators also prefer objects that follow Java Bean standard.

for very simple, small, one-man projects it is probably ok to skip the boilerplate code of getters/setters.  it is just that usually projects tend to grow and expand in time.

another point that can and should be addressed now is the calculator: it feels wrong to me to create instances just to do fine calculation. if we make the analogy to windows calculator, it is like openning a new window each time you want to do a new calculation.  the calculator is stateless: it takes arguments and produces a result. it does not carry any state between calculations.  So I would make the `calculateFine()` method static and have it accept the two arguments.

another issue is the calculation process itself.  all the attributes of a fine are closely related to each other and come in mutually exclusive sets: the result is a textual description of the enum, the amount and points are also linked to it.

I would make these values properties of the enum:

```
public enum FineType
{ 
    NONE("The user was not going above the speed limit, no actions will be taken.", 0, 0), 
    WARNING("No fine issued, no points gained but a warning will be issued to the driver.", 0, 0), 
    FIFTY("A fine of £50.00 will be issued to the driver. 0 points gained.", 50.00, 0), 
    // and so on

    private String description;
    private int    fine;
    private int    points;

    FineType(String description, int fine, int points) {
        this.description = description;
        this.fine = fine;
        this.points = points;
    }

    public String getDescription() { return description; }
    public String getFime() { return fine; }
    public String getPoints() { return p[oints; }
}
```

now you can have the `Fine` take a type in the constructor and fill the properties by itself. this makes the calculator process clearer:

```
public static Fine calculateFine(int speedlimit, int carspeed) {

    int milesover = carspeed - speedlimit;

    if(milesover < 1) { 
        return new Fine(FineType.NONE);
    }
    else if(milesover < 5) {
        return new Fine(FineType.WARNING);
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your design is that you have different fields that, to a certain extent, represent the same property, leading to interdependent state, which makes the code fragile and confusing. I am talking about the class `Fine` and `FineType`. For example, the class `Fine` contains a field `amount`, but it also contains a field `finetype`, both of which represent information about the size of the fine. So it is possible to construct an invalid `Fine` object by assigning the fields `amount` and `finetype` contradictory values, e.g. `amount = 50` and `finetype = FineType.ONE_HUNDRED`. The same applies to the number of points gained.

Since the fields `amount` and `points` already contain all the necessary information regarding the the fine size and the number of points, the question is why you actually need an enum. 3 of the 5 enum values, namely `FIFTY`, `ONE_HUNDRED` and `THREE_POINTS_ONE_FITY`, only represent information that is already stored in `Fine.amount` and `Fine.points`, which means that these enum values are practically useless. So the question arises what the enum is actually supposed to represent. Let's look at the other two values, `WARNING` and `DISQUALIFIED`. Disqualification is an additional action that is taken on top of the fine, and a warning is issued in place of a fine, so both are not really "types" of a fine, but actually have nothing to do with a fine directly.

So how to represent a warning? That probably depends on what you want to do with a warning. Does it have any state associated with it, like a `Fine` object that contains the size of the fine and the number of points gained? If so, it could be a class of its own (and `File` and `Warning` could be subclasses of a common superclass). But judging by your code sample, it doesn't look like it, so maybe it would suffice if the file that contains the driver's registration details has a way of storing the warning without the warning itself being represented as an object, for instance a `List` of dates on which a warning has been issued to the driver.

Similarly, the disqualification is not directly related to the fine, so like the warnings, it could simply be stored in the file with the driver's registration details separately from the fines.

Finally, about the field `result` in the class `Fine`. This should not be a field at all, because its content only depends on the other fields. Instead, I would write a method that generates the `String` based on the values `amount` and `points`, for example like this:

```java
public String getMessage() {
    return String.format("A fine of £%1$.2f will be issued to the driver. %2$d points gained.", amount, points);
}
```

Depending on what you want to do with the class, you could also consider overriding `toString()` to generate this `String`.

Comment: I actually think an enum is a good fit here.  it represents a closed set of valid values. I would question the necessity of `Fine` class.  I think `DriverManager` can accept `FineType` value instead of `Fine` instance

Comment: @Sharon Ben Asher So do you recommend having a single class called FineCalculator with a single static method that takes the 2 speed related parameters, then the calculateFine() function within FineCalculator returns a FineType object, which has the amounts, string result, points etc

Comment: Another thing @SharonBenAsher that I was a bit confused at by your response, was how the calculateFine() method would return a Fine object (that took a FineType object within the constructor) but if FineType has all the necessary values then Fine would effectively be redundant? And now it seems that even the static method within it's own single class seems kind of useless?

Comment: @SharonBenAsher That's true, if a fine can only ever have one of four fixed sets of values, then it would also be appropriate to drop the `Fine` class and only use an enum. In this case, I think a better name for the enum would be `Fine` instead of `FineType`, since it would essentially replace the old `Fine` class.

Comment: @Stingy Do you still recommend having a FineCalculator class with a single static function which uses the Fine class then? That single static would deal with actually calculating how far over the speed limit the user has gone, then returning a Fine

Comment: @daviddone This was Sharon Ben Asher's suggestion, not mine, but I support it. Calculating the fine based on the speed is something procedural, so I think it would be better represented by a `static` method instead of an object that has state. Your approach reminds me a bit of [this](http://www.yegor256.com/2014/05/05/oop-alternative-to-utility-classes.html) demonstration of an apparently ideological aversion to `static` methods.

Comment: @daviddone Come to think of it, the method to calculate the fine can also go into the `Fine` class (or enum) as a kind of static factory method. Maybe that's less confusing than creating a separate class for it.

Comment: I also had the same afterthought to move the calculate logic into the enum as a static factory method.

Comment: @SharonBenAsher Couldn't I then effectively just have one class that's instant based? For example, create a Fine object, set the speed limit and car speed in the constructor, then allow for getPoints, getFine, getDescription methods to be accessible, or is that too much to fit into one class?

Comment: @Stingy also, what do you think?

Comment: Or are you suggesting to leave the FineType as it is and just stick the static function in there and still have it return a FineType? rather than a separate file for the single static function

Comment: you nailed it with the last comment.  this is the very definition of static factory method